# When i move my mouse on the page, it scrolls

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I made a website using html, css and python flask. I use smooth scroll there. When i move my cursor on the first section, it scrolls down. How can i fix that, plus change it so when i click on the first section, the hovering menu doesn't cover the header? How can i add a margin to the first section??
here are the codes:

```
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar">
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#table">ТАБЛИЦА</a></li>
         <li><a href="#problems">ЗАДАЧИ</a></li>
         <li><a href="#rank">РАНК СТУДЕНТОВ</a></li>
         <li><a href="#cheated">СПИСОК СПИСАВШИХ</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
  <section id="table">
    <h1>1</h1>
      <p class="lead"> {{result | safe}} aaaaaa</p
  </section>

  <section1 id="problems">
      <h1>2</h1>
      <p class="lead">bbb</p>
  </section1>

    <section1 id="rank">
      <h1>3</h1>
      <p class="lead">ccc</p>
  </section1>

  <section1 id="cheated">
      <h1>4</h1>
      <p class="lead">ddd</p>
  </section1>

</div>
```

and the css part:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  height: 100vh;
  line-height: 1.6;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: #001247;
}

.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navbar ul li {
  margin: 0 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f4f4f4;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover {
  color: #fdc800;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 70px;
  align-items: start;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;

  scroll-snap-align: start;
}


section1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: start;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;

  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to add margin-top for each section:

```
 scroll-margin-top: 2em;
```